# Issues in not locating physical directory of web site in inetpub/wwwroot

Tags: iis

Are there any issues that I should considered by not putting the physical directory of my websites under inetpub/wwwroot?

I'm placing them under inetpub/ftproot.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider having proper permission on the desired folder when using a different folder other that inetpub\wwwroot. Please make sure you check the article [Default permissions and user rights for IIS 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812614) if you are using IIS 6.0

Comment: it's actually IIS 7

Comment: doesn't matter.. until you have good permission configured on the Web site root folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue if you put your physical website to some other location rather then wwwroot. You just need to make sure your application pool user has access to your website directory.